# Relaunch or Raise

Tags: expressions, translation, french

I'm French and I would like to translate "Relancer un client".

This expression is used, for example, when an invoice has been sent to a customer, but no payment has been received after the expected period of time. More generally, this is used tell again someone to do something.

I found a couple of choices: "To raise a customer" and "to relaunch a customer".

Which one is the most correct?

Comment: Some context would help.

Comment: @RobJarvis "When you ask again to pay to a client" or "When you ask someone again if they've done a task"

Comment: Neither option sounds natural to me. Regarding your comment, I'm not sure what you mean by "ask again to pay to a client". Pay? Are you talking about getting new business from a former client?

Comment: You aren't 'french'; you are French.

Comment: Neither choice is very idiomatic.  And the intended meaning is totally unclear.

Comment: In the specific, formal case of something the person is obligated to do (e.g., pay a bill, or a boss / employer / supervisor reminding an employee to do something),  you could refer to “second notice”, “third notice”, etc.

Answer (score 3):

None of the suggested translations work.

*Relancer* has the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/relancer) **I. B.- 3.** acception, especially the third example:

> **3.** *Au fig.* Poursuivre quelqu'un avec obstination pour en obtenir quelque chose. [*Lisbeth*] *relança les deux tourtereaux jusque dans leur nid au Gros-Caillou* (Balzac, *Cous. Bette*, 1846, p. 231). *Testenel était taillé comme un taureau, mais lent et méticuleux. Sénac venait le relancer huit ou dix fois l'heure* (Duhamel, *Désert Bièvres*, 1937, p. 174).
> − *En partic.* Poursuivre de ses assiduités. *Incapable de surmonter sa déception, de se passer de cette femme, il la relance, elle le fuit* (Proust, Guermantes 2,1921, p. 159).
> − **Renouveler une demande auprès de quelqu'un qui ne s'exécute pas.** *Relancer un débiteur, un fournisseur. Ils convinrent d'aller relancer leur client, le lendemain matin* (Gide, Faux-monn.,1925, p. 1176).

Translation:

> − Chasing someone with persistence to get something out of them.
> − Hit on someone.
> − **Renewing a request to someone who does not comply.**

An usual way to translate ***relancer** quelqu'un* is "**to send a reminder** to someone".

You can also say "...a **gentle/friendly** reminder..." to soften the request.

Answer (score 1):

The most neutral term would be "follow (something) up with a customer", or you could say "chase a customer" if it is not the first time you are reminding them or they are late.

*Relancer* can also imply harrassment (for example, if the client owes you money), in which case "pester a customer" or "badger a customer" would be an idiomatic, informal translation with negative connotations.

Comment: 'Relancer' can be translated as 'dun' in the context of chasing a debt, overdue invoice, etc.